# How to use REST API with flags in iOS application?

Tags: ios, web-services, curl, nsurlconnection

I am new to web services in iOS development. I have a CURL command with flags like -a, -b etc for which I have to call in iOS app. Command without flags are fine but I was unable to find iOS snippets for URL calls with flags. Example command is

```
curl --verbose -a abc.txt -b test.txt http://api.example.com/search.json
```

Thanks, sorry for bad english

Comment: Show the code you're using. Have you checked the CURL docs to find out what the options mean?

Comment: I figured it out and posted the solution in answer. Thanks Dani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and posting the simplified code portion here, Firstly I created cookies from login response:

```
//Passing parameters in post request

NSDictionary* params = @{
                         @"login":username,
                         @"password":password
                         };
NSMutableString* parameterString = [NSMutableString string];
for(NSString* key in [params allKeys])
{
    if ([parameterString length]) {
        [parameterString appendString:@"&"];
    }
    [parameterString appendFormat:@"%@=%@",key, params[key]];
}
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:URL_USER_LOGIN,APP_KEY];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//this is how cookies were created

NSArray* all = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:url];
NSHTTPCookie* currentCookie;
for (NSHTTPCookie * cookie in all) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ : Value: %@", cookie.name, cookie.value);

    currentCookie= cookie;
}
```

And to use the above created cookie I passed it as arguments to function with the name "cookie":

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.example.com/rest.json"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLSession* session =[NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

NSString* Cookie = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",cookie.name,cookie.value];
[request setValue:Cookie forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
__block NSDictionary* jsonResponse;
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    if(!error)
    {
          //do something
    }
    else
         //error
 }];
[task resume];
```

Thanks